# MongoDB using the $ positional operator with multiple element criteria?

Tags: mongodb

Given this document structure (array of objects):

```
{
  "_id" : "2",
  "users" : [{
      "_id" : "1",
      "x"   : "1",
      "y"   : "2",
      "name": "blah"
    }, {
      "_id" : "2",
      "x"   : "2",
      "y"   : "2",
      "name": "blah"
    }],
}
```

I know I can do something like this to replace a particular document in the array:

```
coll.update( {'_id':'2', 'users._id':'2'}, {$set:{'users.$':{"name":"blahblah",... }}}, false, true)
```

**But is it possible to do this when specifying TWO element level criteria that must both be true?** (ie. x and y).  I've only ever seen examples with one, and I can't seem to get it working. Maybe something like this?:

```
coll.update( {'_id':'2', 'users.x':'2', 'users.y':'2'}, {$set:{'users.$':{"name":"blahblah",... }}}, false, true)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to match two fields within the same document you need to use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/) operator.

Your query (where) predicate would then be:

```
{ _id: 2, users : {$elemMatch : {x:2, y:2} } }
```